# Missing Operator in SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to query a baseball database from MS Access, but my SQL Statement keeps getting stuck on a missing operator. Below is the SQL query that I'm passing:

```
SELECT 
    Master.nameFirst, Master.nameLast, 
    Master.nameFirst + ' ' + Master.nameLast as FULLNAME, 
    (SUM(Batting.H) + SUM(Batting.BB) + SUM(Batting.HBP)) / (SUM(Batting.AB) + SUM(Batting.BB) + SUM(Batting.HBP)) as OBP, 
    SUM(Batting.H) / (SUM(Batting.H) + SUM(Batting.BB) + SUM(Batting.HBP)) as HitP, 
    (SUM(Batting.2B) + SUM(Batting.3B) + SUM(Batting.HR)) / SUM(Batting.H) as ExtraP, 
    SUM(Batting.HR) / (SUM(Batting.2B) + SUM(Batting.3B) + SUM(Batting.HR)) as HRP, 
    SUM(Batting.3B) / (SUM(Batting.2B) + SUM(Batting.3B)) as TriplePerc, 
    SUM(Batting.HBP) / (SUM(Batting.BB) + SUM(Batting.HBP)) as HBPP 
FROM 
    Master 
INNER JOIN 
    Batting ON Master.playerID = Batting.playerID 
WHERE
    (Batting.playerID IN (SELECT playerID 
                          FROM Master 
                          WHERE (nameFirst = 'Ryan' AND nameLast = 'Howard'))
```

The missing operator error seems to be focusing on this single expression:

```
(SUM(Batting.2B) + SUM(Batting.3B) + SUM(Batting.HR)) / SUM(Batting.H) as ExtraP
```

But I honestly don't see anything wrong with it. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not simplify the query by removing conditions until you solve the problem?  If you still don't solve it then ask a question.

Comment: Is really `2B` your column name ? That should be the problem. Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Please add - (1) a relevant tag for database+version (2) the DDL of the relevant table (think how easy it would become to support you)

Comment: You are missing one `)` in where clause or is it just typo in query provided?

Comment: My apologies. It's an Access DB I downloaded from a statistician. Yes, 2B is really his field name.

Comment: Also... .please... this is about a missing operator. Not whether or not the fields are named properly.

Comment: If I try to run that SQL and use 'SUM' without having a 'Group By', I get the '...query does not include ... aggregate function...' As recommended above, a good debug method is to delete parts of the query until it works, then look at what you deleted. (1) Get rid of all the 'Sum's) & test; (2) Get rid of the 'Where' & test. Something will become obvious soon.

Comment: I need the INNER JOIN for it to work

Comment: Run your sub-query by itself. Then get rid of all the sum's and try that. Break it apart until you get it to run and that will help you isolate where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Also, just to make a suggestion, if you use aliases, and format your sql, you may find your code easier to read, understand, and debug:

```
SELECT m.nameFirst, m.nameLast, 
  m.nameFirst + ' ' + m.nameLast FULLNAME, 
  (SUM(b.H) + SUM(b.BB) + SUM(b.HBP)) / 
  (SUM(b.AB) + SUM(b.BB) + SUM(b.HBP)) OBP, 
  SUM(b.H) / (SUM(b.H) + SUM(b.BB) + SUM(b.HBP)) HitP, 
  (SUM(b.2B) + SUM(b.3B) + SUM(b.HR)) / SUM(b.H) ExtraP, 
  SUM(b.HR) / (SUM(b.2B) + SUM(b.3B) + SUM(b.HR)) HRP, 
  SUM(b.3B) / (SUM(b.2B) + SUM(b.3B)) TriplePerc, 
  SUM(b.HBP) / (SUM(b.BB) + SUM(b.HBP)) HBPP 
FROM Master m JOIN Batting b 
  ON b.playerID = m.playerID 
     and b.playerId IN 
        (SELECT playerID FROM Master 
         WHERE(nameFirst = 'Ryan' 
           AND nameLast = 'Howard')
```

Comment: It's part of a C# string. Apologies for the poor formatting!

Comment: I think you are missing all of your 'AS xxx' for the calculations? Take a look at 'SUM(b.3B)) TriplePerc, '

Comment: the "as"s are optional in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It is the four lines like:

```
SUM(Batting.H) / (SUM(Batting.H) + SUM(Batting.BB) + SUM(Batting.HBP)) as HitP,
```

should be:

```
SUM(Batting.H) / ((SUM(Batting.H) + SUM(Batting.BB) + SUM(Batting.HBP)) as HitP,
```

or:

```
SUM(Batting.H) / (SUM(Batting.H) + SUM(Batting.BB) + SUM(Batting.HBP) as HitP,
```

**Edit**

Oh my, those were all wrong. It's the closing parenthesis that is missing - or rather leave out the first opening parenthesis:

```
WHERE
    (Batting.playerID IN (SELECT playerID 
                          FROM Master 
                          WHERE (nameFirst = 'Ryan' AND nameLast = 'Howard'))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm ready for football, but are you sure about the 'should be' syntax? The () pairs now seem unbalanced?

Comment: Well, I don't know what the purpose of the calculation is, so the first _divides H with (H + BB + HBP)_ while the second _divides H with H_ and then _adds BB + HBP_. But the last doesn't make much sense, I see now. So the "should be" seems right to me.

Comment: I do the old 'keep a running count of parens, adding 1 for each '(' and subtracting 1 for each ')'. Hope to end with zero. I get one extra '(' with both your 'should be' and 'or:'? Am I missing something?  :)

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: Gosh, weekend mode must be turned on. I better start learning to count ... and looked at the criteria - see edit.